# Can I copy data from one table to another in SQLite using a join condition?

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-insert

I'm trying to copy data from one SQLite table into another using matching data in a different set column across both tables. The second table has spaces and capital letters in the column names.

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1)
SELECT "Column 2"
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column3 = table2."Column 4";
```

Column 3 from Table 1 and Column 4 from Table 2 should match so that the data that is selected and copied from Table 2 into Table 1 is in the right row. I am getting an error message with the code above that says ambigious column name: Column 2. Any advice on how to move this data over while ensuring that the data from Table 2 goes into the correct rows of Table 1?

Sample data:

**table1**

*column1 (animal)*: Null, Null

*column3 (id)*: ID 1, ID 3

**table2**

*Column 2 (Animal Type)*: Cat, Dog, Bird

*Column 4 (ID number)*: ID 1, ID 2, ID 3

Desired results:

**table1**

*column1 (animal)*: Cat, Bird

*column3 (id)*: ID 1, ID 3

**table2**

*No change*

Thank you!

Comment: Qualify "Column 2" with the table's name: `SELECT table2."Column 2"`

Comment: Also, it should be: `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried the following as you suggested, but it does not seem to work as desired. I no longer get the error message, but it does not match the data from the two tables correctly. For example, it has inserted 1803 rows into table1 for a value that only appears in 138 rows in table2. None of those appear to match based on the join condition (all have null value in column 1). 
INSERT INTO table1(column1)
SELECT table2."Column 2"
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column3 = table2."Column 4";

Comment: Edit your question with sample data of both tables and expected results.

Comment: I've now added sample data and expected results, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to `UPDATE` the table `table1`:

```
UPDATE table1
SET animal = (SELECT t2."Animal Type" FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2."ID number" = table1.ID);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xuDK4QEqSxv5ua6EzoU7Yk/0).
Results:

```
| animal | ID  |
| ------ | --- |
| Cat    | 1   |
| Bird   | 3   |
```